# How do I add the navigation menu to the Footer zone in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I want to have my navigation menu show up both where it normally does as well as in the footer. I've tried the following:

```
WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.Menu(), "5");
```

That renders the `<nav>` and `<ul>` elements where I expect them, but there are no `<li>` elements for the actual menu items; it's just rendering an empty menu. Obviously I'm not doing this right. How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Go to widgets and add menu to the footer zone too ( It is already there in the navigation zone)